# Go and Gorilla Mux NotFoundHandler not working

Tags: go, mux, gorilla

I just can't get this NotFoundHandler to work. I'd like to serve a static file on every get request, given that it exists, otherwise serve index.html. Here's my simplified router at the moment:

```
func fooHandler() http.Handler {
  fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Foo"))
  }
  return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func notFound(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  http.ServeFile(w, r, "public/index.html")
}

func main() {
  router = mux.NewRouter()
  fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))

  router.Handle("/foo", fooHandler())
  router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(fs)
  router.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(notFound)

  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router)
}
```

*/foo* works ok

*/file-that-exists* works ok

*/file-that-doesnt-exist* **doesn't work**
- I get 404 page not found instead of index.html

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 39):

The problem is that `router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(fs)` will match every route and the `NotFoundHandler` is never executed.
The `NotFoundHandler` is only executed when the router can't find a matching route.

When you explicitly define your routes it works as expected.

You could do something like:

```
router.Handle("/foo", fooHandler())
router.PathPrefix("/assets").Handler(fs)
router.HandleFunc("/", index)
router.HandleFunc("/about", about)
router.HandleFunc("/contact", contact)
router.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(notFound)
```

Comment: What if the request is not landing to any handler and we are getting bad request in response ? is there anyway to test that scenario ?

Answer (score 5):

This has worked for me

```
r.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(NotFound)
```

Makesure your 'NotFound' function has:

```
func NotFound(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { // a * before http.Request
```